# Querying an access database with format function

Tags: ms-access

I am getting an error i.e "Syntax error(missing operator) for the query expression 's_date>=Format(#12/6/2014#,"Short Date")" and my query is

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE s_date >= Format(#12/6/2014#, "Short Date")
```

Can anyone suggest me what will be the correct query to display the records after the date 12/6/2014??

Answer (score 0):

Is `s_date` a date field?  If so you don't need to format it.

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE s_date >= #12/6/2014#
```

If 's_date` is not a date type then please post an example of how it is stored in your table (I'm assuming some sort of string)